# How to count how many times an iterator will call yield?

Tags: ruby, iterator, yield

I have a method, `foo`, that yields objects. I want to count the number of objects it yields.

I have

```
def total_foo
  count = 0
  foo { |f| count += 1}
  count
end
```

but there's probably a better way. Any ideas for this new Rubyist?

Here's the definition for `foo` (it's a helper method in Rails):

```
def foo(resource=@resource)
  resource.thingies.each do |thingy|
    bar(thingy) { |b| yield b }  # bar also yields objects
  end
end
```

Comment: How `foo` is defined?

Comment: what is wrong with what you have now?

Comment: @akonsu it works, but I was wondering if there's a better Ruby way to do it. E.g. `foo.count`

Comment: @Dennis well, I mean that this is a clear and an easy to understand code. Although, why yield all these objects if you just need their count? But maybe this is outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: @akonsu `foo` is also being called elsewhere, though I could rewrite it not to yield. But say you can't change the method's behaviour, is this the best option you have to count the yields?

Comment: I do not see a better way to count something other than having a counter like you do :). or you can just get `resource.thingies.count`.

Comment: @akonsu I think the only possible drawback to `resource.thingies.count` is it's unclear how many iterations `bar(thingy)` does with its block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any method that calls `yield` can be used to build an [`Enumerator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html) object, on which you can call [`count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count), by means of the [`Object#to_enum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum) method. Remember that when you call `count` the iterator is actually executed so it should be free of side effects! Following a runnable example that mimics your scenario:

```
@resources = [[1,2], [3,4]]

def foo(resources = @resources)
  resources.each do |thingy|
    thingy.each { |b| yield b }
  end
end

foo { |i| puts i }
# Output:
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4

to_enum(:foo).count
# => 4
```

You can pass an argument to `foo`:

```
to_enum(:foo, [[5,6]]).count
# => 2
```

Alternatively you can define `foo` to return an `Enumerator` when it's called without a block, this is the way stdlib's iterators work:

```
def foo(resources = @resources)

  return to_enum(__method__, resources) unless block_given?

  resources.each do |thingy|
    thingy.each { |b| yield b }
  end
end

foo.count
# => 4

foo([[1,2]]).count
# => 2

foo([[1,2]]) { |i| puts i }
# Output:
# 1
# 2
```

You can pass a block to `to_enum` that is called when you call [`size`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-size) on the `Enumerator` to return a value:

```
def foo(resources = @resources)
  unless block_given?
    return to_enum(__method__, resources) do
      resources.map(&:size).reduce(:+) # thanks to @Ajedi32
    end
  end

  resources.each do |thingy|
    thingy.each { |b| yield b }
  end
end

foo.size
# => 4

foo([]).size
# => 0
```

In this case using `size` is sligthly faster than `count`, your mileage may vary.

Comment: how do you pass a parameter to `foo`?

Comment: @akonsu Just pass the additional arguments to the `to_enum` method.

Comment: the documentation says "arguments ... will be passed in method in addition to the item itself." this is confusing, what item? do you know what they are talking about?

Comment: @akonsu Check the documentation for Ruby 2.1, it should be clearer.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Thanks for the edit, but after seeing it I realized in this case the "size" block doesn't make really sense, it's point is to not iterate over the enumerable to compute the size.

Comment: @toro2k True. The size block doesn't affect the return value of `count` anyway.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Actually map/reduce works quite better then counting all the elements, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you otherwise only care about the side-effect of `foo`, you could have `foo` itself count the iterations:

```
def foo(resource=@resource)
  count = 0
  resource.thingies.each do |thingy|
    bar(thingy) do |b|
      count += 1
      yield b
    end  # bar also yields objects
  end
  count
end
```

And then:

```
count = foo { |f| whatever... }
```

You can also ignore the return value if you choose, so just:

```
foo { |f| whatever... }
```

In cases you don't care what the count is.

There may be better ways to handle all of this depending upon the bigger context.

Comment: That could work, but I find it messier than what I have now. Though I could rename `foo` to make it more clear that it yields something _and_ returns a count.

Comment: @Dennis I can understand that. Like I mentioned, it does depend upon the context. What I show encapsulates everything you want about `foo` inside of the definition of `foo`. But it's maybe a little more verbose than some alternatives. There may be a better way to do the whole thing, depending upon what `bar` and `thingies` are. :)